# Unexpected T_FUNCTION, but where?

Tags: php

I've gotten my site to run perfectly on my local machine. However, migrating to production, I get roadblocked by "Unexpected T_FUNCTION ..." error.

I've stripped everything prior to the following code and still get the error reported for line 3. I just can't figure this out.

```
<?php
// Auth Check.
$authCheck = function() use ($app) {         <---- Line 3
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting :

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in **[...][...]** on line **4**

becasue you are using PHP version less than `PHP 5.3.0` upgrade your php or try using `globals`

`PHP 5.3.0+`

```
$app = "Hello Wolrd";
$authCheck = function () use($app) {
    echo $app;
};
$authCheck();
```

`Below PHP 5.3.0`

```
$app = "Hello Wolrd";
$authCheck = function () {
    global $app;
    echo $app;
};
$authCheck();
```

Both would output

```
  Hello Wolrd
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I feel foolish. I was running phpinfo on my test and production sites at once and was checking the wrong page for information regarding my version of PHP.

The truth is that I am indeed running PHP < 5.3.0 on the production server.

Thank you for your assistance and patience.

Comment: Now i make the same mistake with `PHP 5.4` and `PHP 5.3` ... you are welcome

Comment: Actually, the second sample [triggers the same error](http://3v4l.org/lJVim). This have nothing to deal with `global` nor the usage of `use` in an anonymous function. You might consider using [`create_function`](http://php.net/create_function) for any versions below 5.3.0. Or upgrade!