# Syntax error in anonymous function

Tags: php, closures, syntax-error, anonymous-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unexpected T_FUNCTION, but where?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662380/unexpected-t-function-but-where)

This following line of PHP code runs well without any error on my production server WAMP,

```
$filtered_seats = array_filter($seats, function ($seat) use ($seat_no) { return ($seat != $seat_no); } );
```

But when put online, on a Linux server, it exits with the following error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/oya/public_html/ajax.php on line 514
```

Please can anyone explain why this happens? Thanks.

Comment: PHP version? Lamda functions are available from 5.3, it looks like your server is running something older.

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous functions are available since php 5.3 so I would guess that your linux server runs a version < 5.3. See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Answer (score 1):

Check your php version - it looks like you're using PHP < 5.3 (closures were added in 5.3)

Answer (score 1):

Php Anonymous functions were added in PHP 5.3 so i bet you have outdated version somewhere:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php